# XNA Editable text field

Tags: c#, user-interface, xna

I know how to draw text in XNA but I am implementing a level designer that will require the user to enter text into a UI.  I have had a little scoot around on Google but couldn't find how to implement an editable text field.  Is there nothing built into the framework for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use some sort of gui library like
http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com

or use winforms
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the level designer is almost finished.  Just need some simple way of adding a editable text field :(

Comment: Since it's on windows, you could always make the "Edit" button pop up a little pop up form that has a winforms or wpf textbox, and then just send that value back to your xna app.

Comment: OK i think ill have a go at putting in one of the nuclex boxes.  I want this to be multi platform so no point restricting myself to just windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered implementing a level editor for your game by [embedding XNA in WinForms](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)?

Comment: Haha.  I fonly you had said that six months ago.  Level Editor is close to finished this is literally one of the only possible fields that needs editing with text.  Grrrr

Answer (score 1):

If just need a simple way to enter a small amount of text create a class kbHandler

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace CodeName
{
public class KbHandler
{
    private Keys[] lastPressedKeys;
    public string tekst = "";

    public KbHandler()
    {
        lastPressedKeys = new Keys[0];
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
        Keys[] pressedKeys = kbState.GetPressedKeys();

        //check if any of the previous update's keys are no longer pressed
        foreach (Keys key in lastPressedKeys)
        {
            if (!pressedKeys.Contains(key))
                OnKeyUp(key);
        }

        //check if the currently pressed keys were already pressed
        foreach (Keys key in pressedKeys)
        {
            if (!lastPressedKeys.Contains(key))
                OnKeyDown(key);
        }

        //save the currently pressed keys so we can compare on the next update
        lastPressedKeys = pressedKeys;
    }

//Create your own   
private void OnKeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.D0:
                tekst += "0";
                break;
            case Keys.D1:
                tekst += "1";
                break;
            case Keys.D2:
                tekst += "2";
                break;
            case Keys.D3:
                tekst += "3";
                break;
            case Keys.D4:
                tekst += "4";
                break;
            case Keys.D5:
                tekst += "5";
                break;
            case Keys.D6:
                tekst += "6";
                break;
            case Keys.D7:
                tekst += "7";
                break;
            case Keys.D8:
                tekst += "8";
                break;
            case Keys.D9:
                tekst += "9";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad0:
                tekst += "0";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad1:
                tekst += "1";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad2:
                tekst += "2";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad3:
                tekst += "3";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad4:
                tekst += "4";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad5:
                tekst += "5";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad6:
                tekst += "6";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad7:
                tekst += "7";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad8:
                tekst += "8";
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad9:
                tekst += "9";
                break;
            case Keys.OemPeriod:
                tekst += ".";
                break;
            case Keys.Back:
                if (tekst.Length > 0)
                {
                    tekst = tekst.Remove(tekst.Length - 1, 1);
                }                    
                break;

        }

    }

    private void OnKeyUp(Keys key)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
}
```

And in the update loop

```
kb.Update();
string text = kb.tekst;
```

This is a really easy and dirty way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own area that the user can click into.  When they do you need to capture the key presses.

Answer (score 0):

To go along with some of the other suggestions on this thread, you could also use WPF and just render the XNA to a custom user control in xaml. There's a great blog post by Nick Gravelyn on how to do this here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/25/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application.aspx

The great part about this is that you can use techniques like MVVM then to write your editor :-)