# Xbox360 ADK Error

Tags: c#, adk, xbox

I compiled my code and got this error.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Xbox 360
>   ADK\Microsoft.Xbox360.Adk.targets(1372,5): error : Unsupported
>   assembly reference(s):
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll;System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll

After adding some text boxes, labels to the main page I am getting this error. Tried to do a rebuild-all, restart xbox etc, but none of them worked for me.

Edit: Even after removing the Page i am unable to get rid of this error.

Comment: @SonerGönül: it's complaining about a reference, I don't think code is relevent here

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462088/xna-editable-text-field

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what adk is, but it looks like it requires the following references "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll;System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll" as shown in the error.

The XNA libraries for xbox target a reduced version of the .net framework and those aren't included/supported it would seem. You certainly can't use windows controls on an xna project targeting the xbox.

These libraries aren't supported by the xna framework and that's what's causing the error. You should remove them, but you'll then have to fix/re-code anything that relied on them.

Comment: After struggling for a long time, i figured out the answer.

Solution is to add the reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation,remove it and do a clean build. Doing this multiple times solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client". I had similar issue with System.Windows.Controls.dll, but removing it from libraries didn't work. I fixed the error by adding its reference, removing it and rebuild the project.